# How to prove this inequality in weak Lebesgue space

Tags: real-analysis

We have the fact that (here $u\in H_0^1(\Omega),u>0,\text{ in } \Omega ,\Delta u>0\in L^2 \text{ in } \Omega  ,\Omega $ is a bounded domain (smooth),$n=4$)
$$
u\le \frac{c}{|x|^2}*|\Delta u|
$$
How can we deduce that
$$
|\Delta u|_{L^1}^2 \ge c' [u]_{2,w}^2 .
$$

I  want use the weak Young inequality , but the theorem must satisfies $1<p,r,q<+\infty $.Now I don't have other ideas.

Comment: What is $| \cdot |_{2,w}$? And why should the first inequality be correct? Replace $u$ with $u + C$  where $C > 0$, The right hand side is constant and the left hand side can be made arbitrarily large.

Comment: Sorry,i forget to add that $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$,and in fact $u\in W_0^{2,2}$.$[\cdot] _{2,w}$is the norm of weak Lebesgue space.